# Facebook PHP SDK, adding a user to website's backend

Tags: php, facebook

I currently use the Facebook JavaScript SDK to retrieve the e-mail address of the current logged in user in Facebook. So a user clicks Log-in, their email address is displayed in a form field, then they either register or log-in (if they have previously registered).

I have been asked to make it so clicking "Log-in" actually logs them in to the site automatically. I do not understand how this is possible as currently to log-in you require a username and password.

Do I need to actually insert a user into the website's backend?

Not sure if this is allowed but www.dealdash.com is an example of what I need. If you click Log in in the top right of the screen then Sign in with Facebook - it asks you for permission and then afterwards you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I found this graph once, that was very helpful.

[image]